Does the angle between total acceleration and centripetal acceleration change in circular motion?
In a circular motion, if we have a particle moving with changing magnitude in velocity, does the angle between radial acceleration and total acceleration change?

Oh sorry! I meant in regular curved motion. One that doesn't have constant magnitude in velocity.

Knowing that total acceleration is constant Why do you think that?

Does "curved path" mean a circle? The particle could keep constant magnitude radial and tangential acceleration and spiral outward, with constant angle between radial and total acceleration. Or it could keep a constant radius with increasing angular speed, increasing radial acceleration, decreasing tangential acceleration, and varying angle between radial and total acceleration.

If you are familiar with vector calculus, you may directly calculate all these quantities in terms of the parameter that sweeps out the path. You can then see if the angle between any of the vectors you've asked about depend on this parameter.

Even if we know the path is a circle, the answer will depend on how the angular speed changes with time.

I was very confused and didn't know what I didn't understand, but I think know that my question is clear.

If the motion is circular and the radius remains constant like the motion of a marked point on the perimeter of a disk with accelerating angular velocity, the tangential velocity will always be tangent to the circle and the radial acceleration will always point at the centre and they are always at 90 degrees to each other by definition, or am I missing something?

@KDP - everything you said is correct, except that the OP is asking whether the angle between the total acceleration vector and the radial component of the acceleration vector necessarily stays constant in such a motion.

@Amit Thanks. I see I did not read the "homework question" carefully enough. You are right. Seems a strange question to set for homework. (Rolling eyes emoji). 

@KDP Well, I'm quite sure it isn't actual homework considering how the OP went through multiple edits to manage to express the question he really wanted to ask. However, on one account I agree this violates the homework policy -- HW questions aren't necessarily actual HW but just ones that have mostly educational value. In that regard, OP didn't share his work and didn't indicate whether/how he tried to tackle the issue on his own.

Its a bit of a catch 22. The rules say it should not be about a specific computation, so if the OP post his attempt at finding a solution it starts to look like a specific computation.

@KDP I think that "specific computations" refers to stuff like "a pendulum of length L=4m and mass m=5kg..." :) not to derivations of more general kinematic relations like one should perform in order to figure out this particular problem. The resistance to specific computations is just that such questions are basically of 0 interest to a wide audience... (in that regard, this question is completely fine).

@Ahmed_Elsheshtawy Just to be clear, when you say "radial acceleration" can I assume you mean "centripetal acceleration"?

The motion is circular, implying motion along a circle so, working in polar coordinates we may write:
$$ r = \text{const} \Rightarrow \dot{r} = 0$$
$ \vec{r} = r\hat{r} $, so the velocity and acceleration vectors are:
$$ \vec{v} = \dot{\vec{r}} = \require{cancel}\cancel{\dot{r}\hat{r}} + r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}= r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}$$
$$ \vec{a} = \ddot{\vec{r}} = \cancel{\dot{r}\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}}+r\ddot{\theta}\hat{\theta}-r\dot{\theta}^2\hat{r}= r\ddot{\theta}\hat{\theta}-r\dot{\theta}^2\hat{r}$$
Now to write the condition for the angle between the radial acceleration $\vec{a}_r=(\vec{a}\cdot\hat{r})\hat{r}$ and the total acceleration vector $\vec{a}$ to be constant, we can use the dot product:
$$\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a}_r = r\dot{\theta}^2\sqrt{r^2\ddot{\theta}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^4}\cos\alpha = r^2\dot{\theta}^2\sqrt{\ddot{\theta}^2+\dot{\theta}^4}\cos\alpha $$
Where $\alpha$ is the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{a}_r$.
On the other hand, computing the dot product directly from the expression for $\vec{a}$:
$$ \vec{a}\cdot \vec{a}_r = \left(r\ddot{\theta}\hat{\theta}-r\dot{\theta}^2\hat{r}\right)\cdot\left(-r\dot{\theta}^2\hat{r}\right) = r^2\dot{\theta}^4  $$
Equating the above two expressions for the dot product then, we find:
$$ \cos\alpha = \frac{\dot{\theta}^2}{\sqrt{\ddot{\theta}^2+\dot{\theta}^4}} = 
\frac{\dot{\theta}^2}{\dot{\theta}^2\sqrt{\ddot{\theta}^2/\dot{\theta}^4+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\ddot{\theta}/\dot{\theta}^2)^2}}$$
So we've found that if $\ddot{\theta}/\dot{\theta}^2$ is constant, the angle $\alpha$ is constant. Now note that this implies:
$$ \frac{\ddot{\theta}}{\dot{\theta}^2} = -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{1}{\dot{\theta}}\right) = \text{constant}=K\tag{$\star$} $$
We can integrate this expression to find $\theta(t)$:
$$\frac{1}{\dot{\theta}} = K_0-Kt $$
$$ \dot{\theta} = \frac{1}{K_0-Kt} $$
$$ \theta = \theta_0 - \frac{1}{K}\ln(K_0-Kt) $$
I've prepared a little demonstration of this kind of a trajectory in Geogebra: link. You can control the radius and the time parameter ($T_1$ on the page) to see how the motion evolves. The velocity, acceleration and radial acceleration vectors are shown.
Edit: apologies, I didn't explicitly address the crux of your question. The steps above show us that no, the angle $\alpha$ doesn't necessarily remain constant. For a counterexample we can take:
$$ \vec{r} = R(\cos(t^2), \sin(t^2)) \tag{1}$$
So that $\theta(t)=t^2$. We have then $\dot{\theta}=2t$ and $\ddot{\theta}=2$, so that:
$$ \frac{\ddot{\theta}}{\dot{\theta}^2} = \frac{1}{2t^2} $$
Which is clearly not constant in time, therefore the condition marked $(\star)$ will not be satisfied and $\alpha$ will vary during this accelerated circular motion.
Here is a capture from Geogebra, demonstrating how the indicated angle varies during the motion:

It is for the same $\vec{r}$ as in $(1)$, with $R=2$. Here is another Geogebra link where you can also interact with this example.

Is the Geogebra link guaranteed to exist indefinitely?

@Ghoster Ofc not, but I did give the general expression for $\theta$. If I knew how to easily create a gif animation from GeoGebra I would do it so that indeed I could attach it here, I couldn't find a simple way sadly... (any tips?)

Please don’t include a link that will rot.

@Ghoster Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly. In general such links should work as long as the site is functioning. But my answer above is that in general any link over a long period of time may rot

If it will work as long as Geogebra exists, I think that’s fine. I thought maybe it would be gone in two weeks or a year or something.
